# Rbind multiple dataframes together

Tags: r, rbind

I would like to rbind multiple data frames together. These data frames are data from SQL. At times some of the dataframes might be empty.

Code:

```
combined = rbind(df1,df2,df3,df4)
```

If one of the dataframes is empty, it returns a compile error. How do I rbind even if it is empty? Or is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: `do.call(rbind, list(df1, df2, df3, df4))`?

Comment: In base R, @jay.sf's suggestion is certainly the best. I find I prefer (depending on the library set I'm using) `dplyr::bind_rows` or `data.table::rbindlist` (slight code-golf, not sure if there's much more than that for me).

Answer (score 4):

You could use `do.call` and coerce you dataframes into a list

```
do.call(rbind, list(df1, df2, df3, df4))
```

Answer (score 1):

`data.table` offers a `rbindlist` function that works similarly (but is more efficient) than `do.call`-`rbind` combo

```r
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lapply(setDT, list(df1,df2,df3,df4)))
```

You can add `use.names = TRUE` and `fill = TRUE` if your columns are not in the same order in all columns.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `bind_rows`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(mget(ls(pattern = '^df\\d+$'))
```